# How to use ins instruction with GNU assembler

Tags: x86, g++, inline-assembly, att, ioports

How do I use the x86 `ins` instruction with the GNU assembler? The instruction reference suggests the syntax `INS m8/16/32, DX` where e.g. `m16` (I assume) is any 16 bit general purpose register whose only purpose it is to signify whether a byte/word/doubleword should be read, right?

Now, unfortunately, `as` rejects `ins %ax,%dx` with `Error: operand type mismatch for 'ins'`, why is that?

For the record, I know I could simply use `insb` etc. but I'm calling this instruction via inline assembly inside a C++ program and the size of the input to be read depends on a template parameter (and string handling at compile time is not very practical).

EDIT: here is what I have now, for reference (I don't really like the macro)

```
#define INS(T) \
  __asm__ __volatile__("repne \n\t" \
                       "ins" T \
                       : "=D" (dest), "=c" (count) \
                       : "d" (port), "0" (dest), "1" (count) \
                       : "memory", "cc")

template<typename T>
void ins(uint16_t port, uint32_t dest, uint32_t count);

template<>
void ins<uint8_t>(uint16_t port, uint32_t dest, uint32_t count)
{ INS("b"); }

template<>
void ins<uint16_t>(uint16_t port, uint32_t dest, uint32_t count)
{ INS("w"); }

template<>
void ins<uint32_t>(uint16_t port, uint32_t dest, uint32_t count)
{ INS("l"); }
```

Comment: It's supposed to be a *memory* reference, not a register.  The idea in Intel syntax is that you could write `ins dword ptr [rdi], dx` for a 32-bit read (aka `insd`), `ins word ptr [rdi], dx` for a 16-bit `insw` read, etc.  You could maybe even write `ins dword ptr [foo], dx` and get a 32-bit read but the data would be written to `[rdi]` anyway.  Nonetheless AT&T assembler syntax doesn't support this at all and the only way to specify the size is with the operand size suffix.

Comment: You *might* be able to hack it by switching the compiler to use Intel syntax instead, but I think it's going to be painful.  I would try instead to figure out how to just choose the right one of `insb / insw / insl` at compile time.  I don't see why you would need string handling; just write all three and use template specialization or `switch` or whatever to execute the correct one.

Comment: (Don't forget to be careful with your operands, constraints and clobbers; the instruction modifies `rdi`.  And you know that you can't execute these instructions in unprivileged code, unless you've done something such as `iopl()`? I'd assume you are writing kernel or bare-metal embedded code, only it would be a bit unusual for either of those to be C++.)

Comment: @NateEldredge: Ah okay, I understand. I will have to do with some code duplication then I guess. I think I took care of the constraints correctly, I'll check what compiler outputs, and yes I'm writing a kernel.

Comment: Actually, I think it can be done with operand modifiers.  Writing an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's supposed to be a memory reference, not a register. The idea in Intel syntax is that you could write `ins dword ptr [rdi], dx` for a 32-bit read (aka `insd`), `ins word ptr [rdi], dx` for a 16-bit `insw` read, etc. You could maybe even write `ins dword ptr [foo], dx` and get a 32-bit read but the data would be written to `[rdi]` anyway. Nonetheless AT&T assembler syntax doesn't support this at all and the only way to specify the size is with the operand size suffix.

In GCC inline assembly, you can get an operand size suffix `b,w,l,q` matching the size of an operand (based on its type) with the `z` operand modifier.  See [the GCC manual, section "Extended Asm" under "x86 operand modifiers"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm). So if you use types appropriately and add an operand which refers to the actual destination (not the pointer to it), you can do the following:

```
template<typename T>
void ins(uint16_t port, T *dest, uint32_t count) {
    asm volatile("rep ins%z2"
        : "+D" (dest), "+c" (count), "=m" (*dest)
        : "d" (port)
        : "memory");
}
```

[Try it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/49v7dT)

It's important here that the destination be a `T *` instead of a generic `uint32_t` since the size is inferred from the type `T`.

I've also replaced your duplicated input and output operands with the `+` read-write constraint.  And to nitpick, the "cc" clobber is unnecessary because `rep ins` doesn't affect any flags, but it's redundant on x86 because every inline asm is assumed to clobber the flags anyway.

Comment: I am the upvote, but I believe this `asm` statement should be `volatile` given that it relies on the state of what is on an x86 port and that may differ from run to run. You don't want the compiler to optimize away port reads it may think are redundant.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Does volatile make a difference when output operands are specified? I hadn't even though about that and just added the volatile out of habit.

Comment: @Peter If there are no output `=` and no input/output `+` operands then ASM statements are implicitly volatile and specifying volatile is not required. In this case there are input/output operands so if you need it to be volatile you need it to be specified. When using x86 ports and Memory Mapped IO (MMIO) you need to specify volatile to let the code know that there are external changes the compiler isn't aware of that may not produce the same results each time an operation is done.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, if the compiler thinks the output operand is not used afterwards, it can optimize the `asm` away.  I couldn't get it to happen for this example, but here's a more trivial one: https://godbolt.org/z/E75qGe

Comment: @NateEldredge: This solution is indeed much nicer than mine. I also didn't know about `+`. I actually made an error in my question, that should be `rep` not `repne`, I copied that from somwhere else but it doesn't really make sense now that I think about it.

Comment: On a side note I noticed CLANG has a problem with the inline assembly. I mention it, but this is a G++ question so its not really directly relevant.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Interesting, that seems like a clang bug.  It supports `%zN` properly when an explicit type is given, but apparently not when it comes through a template.

Comment: I am under the firm belief this isn't the first time we have encountered this bug (or one related to it) with inline assembly and constraints not working within a template in C++ (and it works fine outside a template). I recall in the last 2-3 years there was some other issue that would have been related to this and I think someone generated a bug report (against llvm/c++). I can't find it, but I am sure it exists.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I found [bug 4348](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4348) which is similar.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is in response to the first version of the question that was asked prior to the major edit by the OP. This addresses the AT&T syntax of GNU assembler for the `INS` instruction.

The instruction set reference for [INS/INSB/INSW/INSD — Input from Port to String](http://INS/INSB/INSW/INSD%20%E2%80%94%20Input%20from%20Port%20to%20String) shows that there are really only 3 forms of the INS instruction. One that takes a byte(B), word(W), or double word(D). Ultimately a BYTE(`b`), WORD(`w`), or DWORD(`l`) is read from the port in DX and written to or *ES:RDI, ES:EDI, ES:DI*. There is no form of the `INS` instructions that take a register as a destination, unlike [`IN`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/in) that can write to *AL/AX/EAX*.

Note: with the `IN` instruction the port is considered the source and is the first parameter in AT&T syntax where the format is `instruction src, dest`.

In GNU assembler it is easiest to simply use either of these 3 forms:

```
insb      # Read BYTE from port in DX to [RDI] or ES:[EDI] or ES:[DI]
insw      # Read WORD from port in DX to [RDI] or ES:[EDI] or ES:[DI]
insl      # Read DWORD from port in DX to [RDI] or ES:[EDI] or ES:[DI]
```

In 16-bit code these instruction would do:

```
insb      # Read BYTE from port in DX to ES:[DI]
insw      # Read WORD from port in DX to ES:[DI]
insl      # Read DWORD from port in DX to ES:[DI]
```

In 32-bit code these instruction would do:

```
insb      # Read BYTE from port in DX to ES:[EDI]
insw      # Read WORD from port in DX to ES:[EDI]
insl      # Read DWORD from port in DX to ES:[EDI]
```

In 64-bit code these instruction would do:

```
insb      # Read BYTE from port in DX to [RDI]
insw      # Read WORD from port in DX to [RDI]
insl      # Read DWORD from port in DX to [RDI]
```

Why do assemblers support the long form as well? Mainly for documentation purposes but there is a subtle change that can be expressed with the long form and that is the size of the memory address (not the size of the data to move). In GNU assembler this is supported in 16-bit code:

```
insb (%dx),%es:(%di)      # also applies to INSW and INSL
insb (%dx),%es:(%edi)     # also applies to INSW and INSL
```

16-bit code can use the 16-bit or 32-bit registers to form the memory operand and this is how you can override it (there is another using `addr` overrides described below). In 32-bit code it is possible to do this:

```
insb (%dx),%es:(%di)      # also applies to INSW and INSL
insb (%dx),%es:(%edi)     # also applies to INSW and INSL
```

It is possible to use the 16-bit registers in a memory operand in 32-bit code. There are very few use cases where this is particularly useful but the processor supports it. In 64-bit code you are allowed to use 32-bit or 64-bit registers in a memory operand, so in 64-bit code this is possible:

```
insb (%dx),%es:(%rdi)      # also applies to INSW and INSL
insb (%dx),%es:(%edi)      # also applies to INSW and INSL
```

There is a shorter way in GNU assembler to change the memory address size and that is using `INSB/INSW/INSL` with the `addr16`, `addr32`, and `addr64` overrides. As an example in 16-bit code these are equivalent:

```
addr32 insb               # Memory address is %es:(%edi). also applies to INSW and INSL
insb (%dx),%es:(%edi)     # Same as above
```

In 32-bit code these are equivalent:

```
addr16 insb               # Memory address is %es:(%di). also applies to INSW and INSL
insb (%dx),%es:(%di)      # Same as above
```

In 64-bit code these are equivalent:

```
addr32 insb               # Memory address is %es:(%edi). also applies to INSW and INSL
insb (%dx),%es:(%edi)     # Same as above
```