# Inline assembly using insl instruction - passing variables in C to registers

Tags: gcc, x86, inline-assembly, xv6

Recently, I read [Xv6, a simple Unix-like teaching operating system](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/xv6.html) and its [source code](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/xv6/xv6-rev7.pdf). There is one example of inline assembly, which I cannot find answer to my question about the implementation. There is a stackoverflow article [How to use ins instruction with GNU assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64945691/how-to-use-ins-instruction-with-gnu-assembler), which cannot help answer that either.

The following is the code snippet I have trouble to understand how inline assembly works for `insl` instruction.

```c
0461 static inline void 
0462 insl(int port, void *addr, int cnt)
0463 { 
0464     asm volatile("cld; rep insl" : 
0465                  "=D" (addr), "=c" (cnt) : 
0466                  "d" (port), "0" (addr), "1" (cnt) : 
0467                  "memory", "cc");
0468 }
```

And one calling function looks like this.

```c
8573     insl(0x1F0, dst, SECTSIZE/4);
```

My understanding about `insl` instruction in GCC transfers a string (of 4 bytes) from a port specified in the DX register to the memory (of double words) pointed to by the ES:EDI as destination index. And, Use the `rep` prefix with the `insl` instruction for a block transfer of CX double words. The questions I have is, not sure how GCC will pass the values of variables `port`, `*addr`, and `cnt` to the registers of `DX`, `EDI`, and `CX`? I tried to find more information in GCC manual, but not. (Please forgive me as a GCC novice. Maybe I did not exhaust all the ways to find it yet.)

I tried to imagine that could be related to **line 0466, "d" (port), "0" (addr) and "1" (cnt)**. If it is true, I still don’t understand why the first argument is listed as "d", and next ones starting from position 0 with "0" (addr) and "1" (cnt). Why not `"0" (port), "1" (addr), "2" (cnt)`? And any rule of the mapping to registers `DX`, `EDI`, and `CX`?

Comment: `rep insl` modifies EDI and ECX, but not DX.  They could and should have written this more simply as `"+D"(addr), "+c"(cnt) : "d"(port) : "memory"` because they're not using separate variables for the outputs vs. inputs.  Maybe this is really old code before GCC added the `+` modifier for read-write operands, which internally invents an input "matching constraint".

Comment: Your "imagine" is correct -- the stuff after the the `:` are "constraints" that tell the compiler how to connect the named values in the C program (addr, port and cnt) to the registers needed by the asm code.  See [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) for more details

Comment: @ChrisDodd, Thanks for advice. Found `cexpresssion` in gcc manual which specifies the arguments in C for registers. However, any clue why "0" and "1" are used, instead of "D" and "c"?

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for advice, which is more advanced than a beginner like me. Good to learn the latest development.

Comment: The `"0"` constraint says "use the same register as the first output".  Since that is `"D"` which can only be one register, it ends up being the same, but for an `"r"` constraint it would be relevant.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I read the related GCC manual about `"0"` before, but not sure what it means. Now I got it. Thanks. 

Do I understand it correctly of below? GCC parses the **output constraint** first, then **input constraint**. `"d" (port)` was not specified in **output constraint**, so needs to be specified. As to `"=D" (addr), "=c" (cnt)` are specified in **output constraint**, so I can (or need to) refer to both by using `"0"` and `"1"` (as the only way?).

Comment: Since `"=c"` only has one register to pick from (ECX for an int-sized object), `"1"(cnt)` to pick "the same register as operand 1" wasn't the only way to write that constraint.  Equally good would be a `"c"(cnt)` input constraint.  A matching constraint is more useful with `"=r"` output operands for a template like `"add %1, %0"` where you can let the compiler pick registers.